# Freezing when execute a command `git add .` and get `fatal: mmap failed: Operation canceled`

Tags: git

These are my additional informations:

- I'm adding ~30 small text files.
- It is okay while I execute `git add <specific-file>` so I think my repository is not broken.
- I also execute this command: `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git add .`
  then get freezing with this log: `15:54:29.382650 git.c:462               trace: built-in: git add .`
- Other repositories on my PC are okay.
- My git version is `2.41.0`.

How do I bypass this error but still keeping old commits?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this on Windows? Is the repository in a directory that is synched to the cloud?

Comment: Hi @j6t No, this is on MacOS. Yes, I'm using Dropbox. I tried to close it then run the command but it did not work.

Comment: *Never ever* operate a Git repository in a directory that is synced to the cloud automatically. These services destroy the repository in no time. But I'm not sure if it has to do with the error you observed.